# Why write an app if a web server will do?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, css

I have a client who wants an app for iPhone, Android, Windows 8 phone, etc.

From his specifications I see no good reason to need an "app" per se. Seems to me CSS,JS and HTML can do the job as long as it's all written with a phone's display in mind.

If his app needed to access localized CPU power or features of a phone device, that'd be one thing, but it's nothing but interaction with a server followed by a display of the results.

Am I not appreciating something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: depends on the nature of interaction. would you have animations? they are comparatively slow in javascript on mobile.

Comment: As we don't know the specifications, we can't tell for sure.

Comment: The "specifications" are that all of it can be performed 100% using HTML,CSS and JS. So what could developing an app on 3 different platforms possibly add?

Comment: Gary, If what you were asking is a rhetorical question that you've already answered yourself and that you don't want to give us the details to, because you were just stating your opinion, and not asking a real question, then perhaps you should go ahead and close/delete your question. After all, for a client who's not used to doing mobile-specific web development, it wouldn't be the first time that such a person would write implementation-details that are a complete mismatch for the project he actually wants built.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering if someone might be able to point out things that apps can do that make them more desirable that just using a web server. The four answers below are evidence that some people understood the question.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say that 'some people understood the question' which implies that some did not - the response that you selected was most definitely not technical/programming related, on a programming/technical site. Therefore it's not fair to expect a marketing/user/customer-perspective response. True, some of the responses below went above and beyond the scope of this site to give you an answer, but that's the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is quite a long and elaborate discussion, most people consider native apps to feel "better". Mind you, this is about real native apps and not the ones produces by PhoneGap etc.

Providing a downloadable app in a store environment gives many people the feel of (free?) marketing power; they expect their app to be "listed" in one of the short lists, the can link from email and other website to the app store and it gives a (fake?) feeling of authenticity. I think this is combined with the effect that some consumers forget they can visit just a website on their smartphone, and are only app-minded.

Besides that; Apple does not approve apps that are a mere UIWebView; the app has to contain a certain amount of uniqueness over a simple web-app. Google has no rules about that, but I don't know Microsofts' rules about that matter.

Many clients don't know what they talk about. They "just want an app". It is your concern to give the best advice, but if they insist.. well.. it maybe takes 4 times the amount of work, and the money...

**edit**
I don't know if this platform is the best place for this discussion. Others can maybe redirect you to another StackExchange site? Nonetheless, this Quora discussion list about [Mobile Website Vs. Native App](http://www.quora.com/Mobile-Website-Vs-Native-App) should also be helpful.

Maybe you can take the opportunity to enrich the designated app a bit. Maybe its not just about simple data presentation, but the powers of an native app can give a better (not just fancier) experience?

Comment: Everybody's answers were great. It's as I was thinking: they like the sexy sound of "app". I'll offer them a choice: open your wallet, or use a web server!

Answer (score 2):

It could be a disconnect in terminology; I agree - if it's only interaction with a server, then CSS/HTML etc is all that's needed.  Perhaps what the client wants/needs is just an icon to click on, rather than a website to visit - maybe it's the app "experience" they're looking for - how the information gets delivered may be secondary?

Answer (score 0):

If the specifications you have at the moment are simply "iPhone, Android, Windows 8 phone, etc", maybe going deeper inside your client's concept of "app" will save you from some headache. I hope for you the app has no particular features other than viewing [remote|local] text and images. If it's not the case, developing for such a wide list of devices and platform will be a *lot* of work.

That said, I already had to develop fast and cheaply business apps for those platforms (Windows Phone excluded), and going with HTML + CSS + JS stack wrapped inside a native container did the job pretty well (and without particular pitfalls).

I suggest you looking at http://cordova.apache.org/, it allows to develop as you would do with a local website and then pack everything inside a native codebox which you can deploy natively to the device.

For a more complete wrapper, with access to *some* native features (like camera, etc) look at http://phonegap.com/.

To develop the "app" code, a good mobile JS based framework can do the work. I normally use Sencha Mobile, it has a bit of a learning curve, but its pretty stable and powerful (as much  as Javascript can be, nothing compared to native code).

Only quirk, I don't know about Windows Phone platform (nor if the aforementioned solutions can work on it).

Hope this was useful. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

IF The requirement is same for all apps then it is okay to develop using any cross platform tools. The upvotes of your question represents the supports of your point. I am just adding some benefits of native app over html5 apps

1. advantage of native apis, features, guis which are not always easy to implement with html5
2. The app store supports has a great advantage
3. native app supports more security options

Just wrote some points in my mind the list might be bigger.